# Sweepline algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, closest-points

I am trying to solve problem CLOPPAIR on spoj in which i have to find the minimum euclidian distance between two points and print the indices of these two points also. I tried to do this using sweepline but still i am getting T.L.E .Can please someone help me?

Here is my code 
http://ideone.com/Tzy5Au

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class node{
    public:
    int idx;
    int x;
    int y;
    node(int xx=0,int yy=0,int ii=0){
        idx=ii;
        x=xx;
        y=yy;
    }
    friend bool operator<(node a,node b);
};
bool operator<(node a,node b){
    return(a.y<b.y);
}
bool cmp_fn(node a,node b){
    return(a.x<b.x);
}
void solve(node pts[],int n){
    int start,last;
    int left =0;
    double best=1000000000,v;
    sort(pts,pts+n,cmp_fn);
    set<node>box;
    box.insert(pts[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        while(left<i && pts[i].x-pts[left].x >best){
            box.erase(pts[i]);
            left++;
        }
        for(typeof(box.begin())it=box.begin();it!=box.end() && pts[i].y+best>=it->y;it++){
            v=sqrt(pow(pts[i].y - it->y, 2.0)+pow(pts[i].x - it->x, 2.0));
            if(v<best){
                best=v;
                start=it->idx;
                last=pts[i].idx;
                if(start>last)swap(start,last);
            }
        }
        box.insert(pts[i]);
    }
    cout<<start<<" "<<last<<" "<<setprecision(6)<<fixed<<best;
} 
int main(){
    int t,n,x,y;
    cin>>n;
    node pts[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>x>>y;
        pts[i]=node(x,y,i);
    }
    solve(pts,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of your solution is `O(N^2)` in the worst case (for instance, it happens if all points have the same `x`). That's too much for the given constraints.

However, it's possible to fix your solution. You should keep points sorted by the `y`-coordinate in a set and iterate only over the [s.upper_bound(curY) - curBest, s.upper_bound(curY) + curBest) range of the set inside the for loop that goes in `x` order. This way, the time complexity is `O(N log N)` in the worst case.

Comment: Thanx Finally got AC .